# Is it Possible to send incall audio stream to pc via wifi from android phone

Tags: android, windows-7, wifi, desktop

I am looking for a way to send incoming call on android phone to pc via wifi. I have to develop a client-server application which connects android phone to pc. But I don't know how to send call audio stream.

In simple words.

I want to attend and answer calls through my pc which has been connected to my android phone via wifi.

Comment: This is not possible because android OS doesn't let you to get call voices for processing and stream it via WIFI or etc.

Comment: This can be done by using Bluetooth by hfp protocol but I don't know how to implement that protocol. so there must be other way around via wifi..